# How do you write a new modifier in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, property-testing

I have come across a few instances in my testing with QuickCheck when it would have simplified things to write my own modifiers in some cases, but I'm not exactly sure how one would do this.  In particular, it would be helpful to know how to write a modifier for generators of lists and of numerics (such as `Int`).  I'm aware of `NonEmptyList`, and `Positive` and `NonNegative`, that are already in the library, but in some instances it would have made my tests clearer if I could have specified something like a list that is not only NonEmpty, but also NonSingleton (so, it has at least 2 elements), or an `Int` that is greater than 1, not just `NonZero` or `Positive`, or an `Int(egral)` that is even/odd, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at how the existing ones were written? What happened when you tried to write similar code to that yourself?

Comment: @DanielWagner I did look at the definitions of Positive and NonEmptyList, but I didn't feel like I came away from that with a full picture of the methods that could be employed, and I also thought asking the question here on SO might make it easier for others to get a handle on this skill more quickly in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's plenty of way in which you can do that. Here's some examples.

## Combinator function

You can write a combinator as a function. Here's one that generates non-singleton lists from any `Gen a`:

```
nonSingleton :: Gen a -> Gen [a]
nonSingleton g = do
  x1 <- g
  x2 <- g
  xs <- listOf g
  return $ x1 : x2 : xs
```

This has the same type as the built-in `listOf` function, and can be used in the same way:

```
useNonSingleton :: Gen Bool
useNonSingleton = do
  xs :: [String] <- nonSingleton arbitrary
  return $ length xs > 1
```

Here I've taken advantage of `Gen a` being a `Monad` so that I could write both the function and the property with `do` notation, but you can also write it using monadic combinators if you so prefer.

The function simply generates two values, `x1` and `x2`, as well as a list `xs` of arbitrary size (which can be empty), and creates a list of all three. Since `x1` and `x2` are guaranteed to be single values, the resulting list will have at least those two values.

## Filtering

Sometimes you just want to throw away a small subset of generated values. You can to that with the built-in `==>` combinator, here used directly in a property:

```
moreThanOne :: (Ord a, Num a) => Positive a -> Property
moreThanOne (Positive i) = i > 1 ==> i > 1
```

While this property is tautological, it demonstrates that the predicate you place to the left of `==>` ensures that whatever runs on the right-hand side of `==>` has passed the predicate.

## Existing monadic combinators

Since `Gen a` is a `Monad` instance, you can also use existing `Monad`, `Applicative`, and `Functor` combinators. Here's one that turns any number inside of any `Functor` into an even number:

```
evenInt :: (Functor f, Num a) => f a -> f a
evenInt = fmap (* 2)
```

Notice that this works for *any* `Functor f`, not just for `Gen a`. Since, however, `Gen a` is a `Functor`, you can still use `evenInt`:

```
allIsEven :: Gen Bool
allIsEven = do
  i :: Integer <- evenInt arbitrary
  return $ even i
```

The `arbitrary` function call here creates an unconstrained `Integer` value. `evenInt` then makes it even by multiplying it by two.

## Arbitrary newtypes

You can also use `newtype` to create your own data containers, and then make them `Arbitrary` instances:

```
newtype Odd a = Odd a deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

instance (Arbitrary a, Num a) => Arbitrary (Odd a) where
  arbitrary = do
    i <- arbitrary
    return $ Odd $ i * 2 + 1
```

This also enables you to implement `shrink`, if you need it.

You can use the `newtype` in a property like this:

```
allIsOdd :: Integral a => Odd a -> Bool
allIsOdd (Odd i) = odd i
```

The `Arbitrary` instance uses `arbitrary` for the type `a` to generate an unconstrained value `i`, then doubles it and adds one, thereby ensuring that the value is odd.

Take a look at the [QuickCheck documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) for many more built-in combinators. I particularly find `choose`, `elements`, `oneof`, and `suchThat` useful for expressing additional constraints.

Comment: I really appreciate that you also added examples of how to use these techniques in Properties.  Excellent answer, thank you for taking the time.